# How can I cluster data using a distance matrix with the ELKI library?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, elki, distance-matrix

I have a distance matrix and I want to use that distance matrix when clustering my data.

I've read the ELKI documentation and it states that I can overwrite the `distance` method when extending the `AbstractNumberVectorDistanceFunction` class.

The `distance` class however, returns the coordinates. So from coordinate x to coordinate y. This is troublesome because the distance matrix is filled only with distance values and we use the indexes to find the distance value from `index x` to `index y`. Here's the code from the documentation:

```
public class TutorialDistanceFunction extends AbstractNumberVectorDistanceFunction {
  @Override
  public double distance(NumberVector o1, NumberVector o2) {
    double dx = o1.doubleValue(0) - o2.doubleValue(0);
    double dy = o1.doubleValue(1) - o2.doubleValue(1);
    return dx * dx + Math.abs(dy);
  }
}
```

My question is how to correctly use the distance matrix when clustering with ELKI.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractNumberVectorDistanceFunction` is the approriate parent class *only* if your input data are number vectors. If your **data type** is abstract object identifiers, subclass `AbstractDBIDRangeDistanceFunction` instead. You then have to implement

```
double distance(int i1, int i2);
```

There are already different implementations of a distance function for precomputed distances, for example `DiskCacheBasedDoubleDistanceFunction` that memory-maps a distance matrix stored on disk. We should add a `DoubleMatrixDistanceFunction` though, for direct use from Java (in the next version, all class names and package names will be shortened, btw).

See also: https://elki-project.github.io/howto/precomputed_distances
in particular the section titled "Using without primary data", on how to set up a database with no primary data, when you only use a distance matrix.

Comment: Does this support asymmetric matrices?